# How to find OSM way IDs with missing maxspeed?

Tags: osmnx

I'm trying to identify highways whose ways have a missing maxspeed tag so that volunteers can add it and make highway routing better.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in OSMnx.  I have gotten this far:

```
G = ox.graph_from_polygon(geom, network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)
for row in edges.itertuples():
    print ( row )
```

So I get a list of way IDs in the row output.  BUT: The ways with missing maxspeed tags are NOT shown (at least I can't identify them easily).  For example, way ID 942999393 presently has no maxspeed.

https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/942999393

The print output looks like this (I omitted many way IDs for clarity):

> Pandas(Index=(176685998, 83756471, 0), osmid=[... **942999393** ...many way IDs], ref='US 491', highway='trunk', junction=nan, oneway=False, reversed=False, length=32580.930999999997, geometry=<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f8d4b6b5f40>, lanes=['3', '4', '2'], **maxspeed='30 mph'**, bridge='yes', name=['US Highway 491', 'East Center Street', 'East Central Street'])

As you can see, the row has a **maxspeed='30 mph'** attribute, presumably because the other ways in the row have that attribute.

Any ideas?  Is there is some magic function to inspect each way and look at its attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the answer through experimentation.  The key is to add the flag **simplify=False** when constructing the graph:

> G = ox.graph_from_polygon(geom, network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf, **simplify=False**)

Then the following code works.  The **maxspeed** member's type needs to be inspected.  If there is a speed limit, this will have a string value.  If there is no speed limit, it will be float('nan')

```
# Ways without a speed limit
waysmissingmaxspeed = []
for row in edges.itertuples():
    if type ( row.maxspeed ) is str:
        pass                            # Speed limit present as a string
    elif math.isnan ( row.maxspeed ):   # Speed limit seems to be float('nan')
        waysmissingmaxspeed.append ( row.osmid )
    
waysmissingmaxspeed = list ( set ( waysmissingmaxspeed ))   # Make a list of unique IDs
print ( waysmissingmaxspeed )
```